# Dates are not getting displayed according to the customize TimeZone. Always picking the default timezone

Tags: java, datetime, jackson, datetime-parsing

Tried all possible combinations, created a Custom `JsonDeserializer` class as well modified the `DateFormat` as per my need. But still no fruitful result.

But result always display date in 'EST' Sat Jan 01 14:08:56 **EST** 2000.
I want my date to be displayed in UTC or it should be more configurable as per the client needs.

```
public class CustomJsonDeserializerWithDateFormat extends JsonDeserializer<Date>{

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); 
        TimeZone TZ = TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TZ); 
        dateFormat.getCalendar().setTimeZone(TZ);
        Calendar newCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        newCalendar.setTimeZone(TZ);
        dateFormat.setCalendar(newCalendar);
        //ZonedDateTime 
        System.out.println("Time Zone : "+dateFormat.getTimeZone());
        JsonToken t = p.getCurrentToken();

        if (t == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
            String value = p.getText().trim();
            try {
                Date formattedDate = dateFormat.parse(value);
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat
                        ("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
                TimeZone central = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
                formatter.setTimeZone(central);
                Date fromDate = (Date)formatter.parse(formattedDate.toString());

                System.out.println(fromDate);

                DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu" , Locale.ENGLISH );
                ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( formattedDate.toString() , f );
                System.out.println(zdt.toString());
                ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );
                ZonedDateTime zdtChicago = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( z );
                System.out.println(zdtChicago.toString());
                return fromDate;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: In fact I tried all below combinations as well  but always result is the same.
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
TimeZone TZ_UTC = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"); 
mapper.setTimeZone(TZ_UTC);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); 
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TZ_UTC);
mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
Reading a JSON file and populating a Map from it.
Then,using 'mapper.convertValue' to do the further conversion.
**mapper.convertValue(classMap,RuntimePropertyData.class)**;

Comment: Input date : 2000-01-01T12:08:56.235-0700
Output date : Sat Jan 01 14:08:56 EST 2000 (Always in EST inspite of changing it to UTC in dateFormat)
Following is set as a property on the attribute in RuntimePropertyData.java
@JsonProperty("begin-date")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDeserializerWithDateFormat.class)
private Date beginDate;

Comment: If you have more code to add, please **[edit]** the question, it's much more readable than putting in the comments

Comment: Please don't put that code into a comment but rather [edit] your question.

Comment: Any particular reason to mix `SimpleDateFormat` and `DateTimeFormatter`? If you have the new `java.time` classes available, it's much better to use only them.

Comment: No reason I just tried to get the things done. I tried everything.

Comment: Your code returns a `java.util.Date`, and this class [doesn't have a timezone](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). When you print a `Date`, it uses the JVM default timezone, but the date itself doesn't have this information. That's probably what's confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the new `java.time` classes available, there's no need to mix them with old `SimpleDateFormat`. To parse the input `2000-01-01T12:08:56.235-0700`, just use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` and parse it to a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` - the best choice for this case, as it represents a date and time (2000-01-01T12:08:56.235) in a specific offset (-0700).

Then you convert it to a `java.util.Date`, using the `from` method. Your deserializer will be as simple as this:

```
public class CustomJsonDeserializerWithDateFormat extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    // will deserialize inputs in the format "2000-01-01T12:08:56.235-0700"
    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX");

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // parse input
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(p.getText(), fmt);
        // convert to java.util.Date
        return Date.from(odt.toInstant());
    }
}
```

I also recreated your class and tested with some sample data:

```
public class RuntimePropertyData {

    @JsonProperty("begin-date")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDeserializerWithDateFormat.class)
    private Date beginDate;

    // getter and setter
}

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("begin-date", "2000-01-01T12:08:56.235-0700");
RuntimePropertyData data = om.convertValue(map, RuntimePropertyData.class);
System.out.println(data.getBeginDate());
```

Now that's the tricky part. A `java.util.Date` [doesn't have any timezone information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/). This class has only one value: the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`, or *"January 1<sup>st</sup> 1970 at midnight in UTC"*). It simply represents an instant, a specific point in time.

When I `System.out.println` a `Date` (or when I log it, or check its value in a debugger), it implicity calls the [`toString()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--), and it converts the date to the JVM default timezone. So, when you see `Sat Jan 01 14:08:56 EST 2000`, that's the result of `Date`'s `toString()`.

---

If you want to change the format when serializing the date, you can annotate your field with `@JsonFormat`, and also set the desired timezone:

```
@JsonProperty("begin-date")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDeserializerWithDateFormat.class)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX", timezone = "UTC")
private Date beginDate;
```

Then, if I serialize it:

```
// data is the same RuntimePropertyData I've got from the code above
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(data));
```

This will produce the following JSON (with the date in UTC):

> {"begin-date":"2000-01-01T19:08:56.235Z"}

To change the timezone, you can also set in the `ObjectMapper`. In this case, I must remove it from the annotation:

```
@JsonProperty("begin-date")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDeserializerWithDateFormat.class)
// just the format, without timezone
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX")
private Date beginDate;
```

And then I set the timezone in the mapper:

```
om.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago"));
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(data));
```

Now the output is:

> {"begin-date":"2000-01-01T13:08:56.235-0600"}

Unfortunately, if I set the timezone again, it doesn't change the output anymore (I'm using Jackson 2.8.8). Apparently, the timezone used in the first serialization is kept, and further modifications have no effect - so, if you want a highly customized output (where the timezone can always change), the solution is to always create a new `ObjectMapper`.